# Using ASP.NET session in WCF = Session lost every call

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, session

I'm trying to do a WCF webservice to post some data to clients. Clients has to authenticate before accessing data, so I've made a method to authenticate, method which sets some session variable.
When I try to access this sessions variables in another method, they're always NULL (I've tried with WCF test client and a little Winforms test client).

I've already set **aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"**  my web.config and add attribute to my Service class **[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]**.

this test :

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session[CONST_SESSION_AUTHENTICATE] != null &&        (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session[CONST_SESSION_AUTHENTICATE] == true)
```

always refers to null session variable ...

What did I miss ?

Thanks

Comment: Can I suggest you're going about this the wrong way? Try passing a token in the header rather than trying to make a mechanism designed to be stateless use session!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you call your service ? You must use the same service client object and allow cookies. The session will work only if the client sends back the cookie created by ASP .NET.

Here is an example:

http://stack247.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/enable-cookies-session-in-wcf-aspnetcompatibilityrequirements/

Comment: I used WCF test client provided with Visual Studio to test. And on my Winform application, I use a service reference. Does this means that WCF session only works with ASP website calls ?

Comment: With the WCF test client it won't work, but with add service reference will work if you open the App.Config and set allowCookies=true on the binding.

Comment: Basically, you need a client which support cookies (When you do the first request, the ASP .NET server will send a cookie back which the client will store and send back with every request for identification). When you add service reference and enable cookies, you need to use the same serviceClient object for other requests (every serviceClient you create has its own cookie container).

Comment: That's what I presume about WCF test client. Thanks for enablecookie on client app.config !